# Выбрать только один символ, если он имеется.

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Научите, на примере, как выбрать только один из символов, а остальные пропустить. 
Вот строка -

```
var str = '\n\ntest\n\ntest\n\n';
```

Первые символы, переноса строки, нужно удалить, и оставить только

> test\n\ntest\n

Я бы лучше ничего не показал, но ведь все равно скажете - "показывай что сделал сам", по этому вот -

```
var str = '\n\ntest\n\ntest\n\n';

var re = /^\n*([\s\S]+)вот тут что-то нужно написать, чтобы оставить только один перенос строки/g;
var source;

while((source = re.exec(str)) != null){
    console.log(source)
}
```

**Дополнение:**

[image]

Видете, у меня строки выводятся в консоль на разных строках, что означает, что в конце строки стоят переносы строки \n, как у Вас в примере. Если бы их небыло, то в консоль вывелось бы одна строка. Смотрите пример ниже.

[image]

Comment: @vas, а может просто не "*что-то нужно написать*", а просто убрать флаг **g** ("*глобальный поиск*")?

    var str = '\n\ntest\n\ntest\n\n';
    var re = /^\n*/;
    console.log(re.exec(str)); // ["\n\n"]

Comment: @vas, код в комментах: пустая строка перед блоком кода + отбивка по 4 пробела для каждой строчки внутри этого блока.

Текст
---------------Пустая строка  
----Строчка кода  
----Строчка кода  
----Строчка кода

Comment: @vas, запутали )) То есть, судя по результату, который вы хотите получить, вам надо убрать все символы из начала строки и один в конце? 

    var str = '\n\ntest\n\ntest\n\n',
        re = /^\n*|\n{1}$/g;
    str.replace(re, '');

Хотя, сейчас я уже ни в чём не уверен ;)

Comment: @vas потратьте время не на изучение методом тыка, а прочитайте что-нибудь, [типа такого](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: я говорю про то что у вас не

"text**\n\n**text\n----\ntext\n"

а

"text**\n**text\n----\ntext\n"

Comment: Жесть какая-то. Так замудренно все.  

    text.replace( /^\n+/, "\n" ).replace( /\n+$/, "\n" )

Так должно работать?

Comment: @ReinRaus в изначальном варианте ? нет, надо в начале все убрать переводы :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 /^\n*|\n+(?=\n$)/                       __
  | | | |      |_в конце строки           |
  | | | |  |_за которым следует один \n   |-блок ИЛИ
  | | | |_один или более \n             __|
  | | |_============ИЛИ=============     
  | |_ноль или более \n
  |_в начале строки
```

домашнее задание: преобразуйте строку

```
 "\n\n\ntext\n\ntext\n\n----\n\ntext\n\n"
```

к виду

```
 "text\n\ntext\n----\ntext\n"
```

(**"`----`"** - разделитель строк)

Comment: @eicto, Спасибо! У меня ещё вопросы появились.   
Как мне объяснить мозгу, что регулярные выражения для метода exec и replace === разные? Вот Ваше выражение работает с replace, но не работает с exec. Почему? В чем разница?  
И другой вопрос - что означают черточки в Ваitv примере?

И статью в вики я прочел, но, к сожалению, не обнаружил чего-то нового.

Comment: Вроде получилось сделать домашнее задание, получилось очень быстро сделать, почти с первого раза, но если честно, то мне кажется, что это случайность))))  
var str = '\n\n\ntext\n\ntext\n\n----\n\ntext\n\n';
var re = /^\n*|((\n{1})(?=\n))/g;
//"text\n\ntext\n----\ntext\n"
console.log(str.replace(re, ''));

Comment: @vas [неправильно](http://jsfiddle.net/od4Labv8/), двойной \n съедается везде, а должен только в начале, в  конце и перед разделителем.

> Метод exec при совпадении возвращает массив и обновляет свойства объекта regexp. Если совпадений нет - exec возвращает null.

на replace вообще не похоже, больше всего похоже на шаг match

Comment: @eictо, написал в вопросе. Дольнейшее обсуждение давайте на верх перенесём :)